# Application fails to run on other computers

Tags: c#

My first issue came from being unable to get clickOnce to work. It was failing immediately with either no message or two message boxes - one that said [name of program] has stopped working and one that asked if i want to send more information while offering more information that seems meaningless.
There is perhaps a clue in the fact that this would not even work on my computer.
I then decided to use the debug folders .exe as a part time solution. This works when run from my computer but not from others, including the computer i developed an older version of the program on(although many new libraries have been added since). It fails with the same error message from cickOnce.

I used WinDbg to see what differed between my PC and the old development PC. 
The only difference i noticed was the working PC had this:

```
ModLoad: 000007fe`fbaf0000 000007fe`fbb06000   C:\Windows\system32\netapi32.DLL

ModLoad: 000007fe`fbae0000 000007fe`fbaec000   C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll 

ModLoad: 000007fe`fc180000 000007fe`fc1a3000   C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll 

ModLoad: 000007fe`fbac0000 000007fe`fbad5000   C:\Windows\system32\wkscli.dll two windows
```

While the broken PC had this:

```
ModLoad: 000007fe`f7f40000 000007fe`f7f5e000   C:\Windows\system32\LMIRfsClientNP.dll
```

I cant see why they differ or if that is even important?

I also used Dependency walker. From this i saw that there were issues with differing CPU settings. Everything but the exe was X64 so i added a new x64 option through the configuration manger and set the exe project to use that which got rid of the notices in dependency walker but did not solve my issue.

I also tried a release build but no luck.

Does anyone have any solutions or suggestions as to how i can find out more about what might be causing this?

Comment: Start with a very simple ClickOnce app (something which just displays a message box) and ensure that you installed the correct version of .Net on the target computer. Once you have that working, add stuff until it breaks...

Comment: Check your Event Logs - any errors in there?

Comment: Empty WPF app runs no bother. It is a very large program but i will strip it down if it comes to that. I use NLog but nothing is being created. I will look into this but i think it fails before it has time to use NLog.

Comment: I checked the Event Viewer and found exception Info: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException followed by a stack trace. not sure what this means but looks like progress!

Comment: @user3350158 If all the compiling options are the same, I bet it has something to do with libraries.  Make sure that your target machine has them (and they're the same versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that the target machine has the same .NET version that you're compiling for.  Also, make sure that if it's running on a 32-bit system, that you're not compiling for the 64-bit.  Lastly, make sure that you're including all of the necessary libraries.  Just by looking at those errors, there's obviously some sort of problem with either missing dependencies or maybe permissions?  Hopefully you're not facing a case of [dependency hell](http://areyoufuckingcoding.me/2012/04/16/dpendency-hell/).

Comment: Target machine is 64 bit. I am compiling for 64 bit only to keep things simple. I am aiming at .net 4.0 but i do use older libraries. I will look into permissions.

Comment: what kind of issues do you think i might be getting with permissions. Not sure what might apply to me

Comment: @user3350158 Try compiling it for 32 and see if that fixes it. As far as permissions, not sure, but I've had different issues in the past. One of machines did not allow installation of any programs without running the installation process under administrator. I did not have much time to spend with it, so I never got a chance to discover why (I'm sure it had to do with permissions on directories... perhaps Temp).

Comment: You get it for the permissions hint. My major break through came from realising to check the basic Windows Event Viewer - embarrassed to say i never even knew this existed. This showed me an Autofac error which didn't mean much but prompted me to install a trial version of Visual Studios on another computer to see if i could get more info. Instead i got a prompt about not connecting to the database where i realised the new live DB did not give permissions to the other computers in the company. The autofac error came about from not being able to retrieve info from the database to inject.